# Collectstatic is copying too many files on my openshift instance

Tags: django, openshift, collectstatic

I would like to use the collectstatic option in my openshift django instance but it appears to be copying loads of unneeded files.

An example line of output

```
Pretending to copy '/var/lib/openshift/519017e25973ca1ead00035b/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/contenttypes/locale/da/LC_MESSAGES/django.po'
```

Here are some snippets from settings.py

```
if 'OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR' in os.environ:
    # Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wsgi.application'
    DEBUG = False
    DB_ROOT = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR']
    STATICFILE_DIR = os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'wsgi', 'static', 'mysite')
    TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'wsgi', 'templates')
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'wsgi', 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (STATICFILE_DIR,)
```

"ls -R $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/ | grep virtualenv" yields no results

ls -R $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR../.. | grep virtenv does show a bunch of old virtenvs

Also, this seems strange:
> ls -la $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR

```
drwxr-xr-x.  11 xxxx                     xxxx    4096 Jan 26 11:45 python
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root                     root      50 Jun  7  2013 python-2.7 -> /var/lib/openshift/519017e25973ca1ead00035b/python
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the virtualenv is somehow being included (perhaps via a symlink) in the `STATICFILE_DIRS` setting. If you do `ls -R` on `STATIC_ROOT` do you see anything that should be there?

Answer (score 0):

For others who may experience the same issue.

This was caused by the version of settings.py on openshift being out of sync with my local copy. I had set the STATICFILE_DIR incorrectly and checked it in at some point.

Answer (score 0):

In Django the STATIC_ROOT is the location where the static files get copied to when you run `collectstatic`. STATICFILES_DIRS is where collectstatic looks for static files to collect. In your case you have STATIC_ROOT set to `$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/static` and STATICFILES_DIRS set to STATICFILE_DIR which is set to `$OPENSHHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/static`.

So you are copying files from `wsgi/static` and placing them in `wsgi/static`. This seems that it might be causing a type of circular situation where it will copy the same files over and over again.

Make sure that STATIC_ROOT is not included in STATICFILES_DIRS.